# How to properly search php

Tags: php, mysql

Whats wrong in my query? What I want to happen is, when I search a number in order id the output will be what I input in search bar for order id. Whats happening right know is when I enter a number all the "Accepted" and "Dispatched" is included.

This is my code right now.

```
<?php 
session_start();

$order_id = $_SESSION['order_id'];

if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}
$_SESSION['navMenu'] = "order";
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

require_once 'includes/database.php';
include_once 'system_menu.php'; 
include_once 'ordermodal.php';
include_once 'ordermodal2.php';

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM cart_tbl";
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Hong_Kong"); 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM order_tbl WHERE order_status = 'Accepted' or order_status = 'Dispatched' or order_status = 'Pending'";
/*** * SET UP COMBO BOX FOR SEARCH */
$comboBox = isset($_REQUEST['comboBoxVal']) ? trim($_REQUEST['comboBoxVal']) : '';
$search_by = isset($_REQUEST['search_by']) ? addslashes($_REQUEST['search_by']) : 0;
$orders= null;

if ($comboBox != '') { 
    switch ($search_by) { 
        case 1://Order ID
            $sql .= " AND order_id LIKE '%{$comboBox}%' ";
            break;
        case 2://Driver Number
            $sql .= " AND driver_number LIKE '%{$comboBox}%' ";
            break; 
    } 
}
$carts = mysqli_query(connection2(), $sql2);
$orders = mysqli_query(connection2(), $sql);
$search_filters = array(1 => 'Order ID', 2 => 'Driver Number');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lot wrong with query construction.

For example you case statement, either `case 1` or `case 2` would be executed not both of them as you put `break` at the end of `case` statement.

```
if ($comboBox != '') { switch ($search_by) { 
 case 1://Order ID
 $sql .= " AND order_id LIKE '%{$comboBox}%' ";
    break;
case 2://Driver Number
 $sql .= " AND driver_number LIKE '%{$comboBox}%' ";
    break; 
    }
```

On the other hand, at the end you are trying to bind two holder.

```
$search_filters = array(1 => 'Order ID', 2 => 'Driver Number');
```

But, I'm wondering how it is going to work ?

The best option is, debugging the constructed SQL to identify whether your query is getting properly constructed or not.

When you are about to execute your constructed SQL. Add following code :

```
 echo $sql;
```